Azure load balancer for Istio Ingress not configured as expected
I have the following configurations and I do not understand why the Load Balancer is configured as it is:
I expected the following outcome in the load balancer
Front end 9080, Backend a node port (which routes to Istio ingress clusterip 8090).
Is the Azure load balancer configured as expected based on the manifest file? If so how does it work?
Load balancer in Kubernetes Manifest File
 apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: istio-ingressgateway
      #namespace: istio-system
    spec:
      selector:
        istio: ingressgateway
      ports:
      - name: http
        port: 9080
        targetPort: 8080
     

Resulting load balancer JSON View in Azure Portal
                        "frontendPort": 9080,
                        "backendPort": 9080,
                        "enableFloatingIP": true,
                        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                        "protocol": "Tcp",
                        "loadDistribution": "Default",


                


"probes": [
            {
                "name": "***-TCP-9080",
                "id": "***",
               
                "properties": {
                    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                    "protocol": "Tcp",
                    "port": 32700,
                    "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                    "numberOfProbes": 2,
                    "loadBalancingRules": [
                        {
                            "id": "/****-TCP-9080"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/probes"
            }]
            }


The Azure Load Balancer works by distributing incoming traffic among the healthy instances of services defined in a backend pool. When you create a Kubernetes service of type LoadBalancer, AKS automates the configuration of the Azure Load Balancer.
Here's how to set up a LoadBalancer service in AKS that listens on the frontend port 9080 and routes traffic to a backend node port which then directs traffic to Istio's ingress gateway. First, you need to have Istio installed on your AKS cluster. You can do this using Istio's istioctl tool or enabling it from portal while setting up aks cluster-

Next, you need to create a Kubernetes service that exposes the Istio ingress gateway.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway-external
  namespace: aks-istio-ingress
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway  # Ensure this matches the label on your Istio ingress gateway pods
  ports:
  - name: http2
    port: 9080
    targetPort: 8090  # The port on which Istio ingress pods are listening for HTTP traffic
  loadBalancerIP: 4.156.123.38  # Use the static external IP if needed or remove this line for dynamic IP

apply it with kubectl apply -f <filename.yaml>

If you specifically want the backend port in the Azure Load Balancer to reflect 8090, you should set the targetPort in your Kubernetes Service to 8090. But remember, this targetPort is internal to the cluster and does not need to match the Azure Load Balancer's frontend or backend port. Here In this configuration, type: LoadBalancer creates an Azure Load Balancer service. port: 9080 is the port you want to expose externally on the Azure Load Balancer and  targetPort: 8090 is the port on the Istio Ingress Gateway where the LoadBalancer will send the traffic. This should match the port that the Istio Ingress Gateway service listens on for incoming traffic.
